# Is the thread created in C# user level or kernel level?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Recently I was studying the operating system, and came across this question.

Is the thread created in C# user level or kernel level, like:

```
Thread mythread=new Thread(ThreadStart(something));
```

As far as I know, the process with cpu-intensive thread on kernel level **could run faster than those on user level.**  Because the book Modern operating system says *"The schedule of user-level thread will not trap into kernel,that's why they are more lightweight compared with kernl-level thread".*
So I think user-level thread could not run on different cpu,which requires trapping into kernel.

And in linux,the thread created by `pthread_create` is kernel level. So I'm curious about the feature of .Net C#.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is unix terminology, on Windows you'd say "fiber or thread".  The term "green thread" is also a pretty common way to say "user thread".

It is not up to C# nor the CLR to decide this, it is the *CLR host* that determines this.

The host is the glue that marries the CLR to the operating system or the host process.  Programs that target Silverlight, .NET Compact, .NETCore, Xbox, Windows Phone, Hololens, etc always have a custom host to adapt to the target's OS.  IIS and SQL Server are common examples of unmanaged programs that have a custom host to allow managed code execution, respectively ASP.NET and CLR stored procedures.  Lots of other programs allow scripting in C# with a custom host, AutoCAD is the canonical example.

So the CLR does not create a thread itself, it asks the host to do it.  The [ICLRTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/iclrtask-interface) and [ICLRTaskManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/iclrtaskmanager-interface) interfaces get that job done.  The thread pool is a host duty as well, [ICorThreadpool interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/icorthreadpool-interface).

So it is formally unknowable that you'll get a fiber or thread.  Notable is that these interfaces were added at the request of the SQL Server team.  They were heavily invested in fibers at the time and wanted the option to execute CLR stored procedures on a fiber.  Got it all done, but at roughly the same time the multi-core revolution of the early 2000s upset that apple-cart.  And they did not actually ship it.  I am not aware of any host that uses fibers, albeit that you can never be sure with custom hosting being common.

So it is pretty safe to assume that you'll get a "kernel thread".

Comment: What about `pthread_create` in linux,is it user or kernel?And is it true that user thread could not run on different cpu?

Comment: The pthreads library creates normal everyday threads that run concurrently with other threads in the process.  The term "user thread" is really clumsy, it just doesn't have anything to do with threading at all.  The kernel is completely unaware of it and doesn't know any better than that it is normal code.  No concurrency whatsoever, all it does is switch context.  Something that has to be done manually by the code itself, SwitchToFiber() on Windows.

Comment: I found the term "user thread" on the book _Modern Operating System_,maybe it's out of date.

Comment: @HansPassant isn't this related to what multithreading model does the operating system implements? (many-to-many, many-to-one, one-to-one)

Answer (score 3):

They are created within the context of the process. Of course there is some layers/information that has to go to the kernel, but it belongs to the process.

If this didn't happen, threads could introduce a privilege escalation which would be a huge security problem.

Comment: Does that means the whole process could only run and dispatched on one cpu,and could not take advantage of the multi-cpu system?

Comment: @bigxiao not at all. thats the point of threads is that they can be scheduled independently of each other

Comment: And hence an application process owned thread is a "user mode" thread.  On Windows I believe only the OS can create "kernel mode" threads.

Comment: @JasonCoder i'm sure on linux its the same way otherwise that would be privilege escalation.

Comment: @DanielA.White But as far as I know,different threads share the same resource in one process,how could that happen if they are on different CPU?

Comment: @bigxiao a process is assigned a range of memory.

Comment: @DanielA.White It's ture for the kernel level threads,but for user level,is it possible to run on different CPU?Because I think scheduling threads on different CPU need the participation of kernel.

Comment: @bigxiao yes. What makes you think they can’t? The kernel is responsible for scheduling user land threads too

Comment: @DanielA.White Because the book **Modern operating system** says "The schedule of user-level thread will not trap into kernel,that's why they are more lightweight compared with kernl-level thread".So I think user-level thread could not run on different cpu,which requires trapping into kernel.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate more on Hans answer usually operating systems implement multithreading models to define the relationship between user and kernel level threads. Common ways of establishing such relationships are: **many-to-one, one-to-one, many-to-many.**

- **Many-to-one** - maps many *user-level* threads to a kernel thread. Used to be a thing back when multiple processing cores where not yet available.
- **One-to-one** - maps each *user-level* thread to a kernel thread. Linux and Windows operating systems implement this model.
- **Many-to-Many** - maps many *user-level* threads to many kernel threads. Before version 9 Solaris used to support this model.
- There is one last variation of many-to-many model, where user thread may still be possible to be bound to one kernel thread, this model is called two-level model.

So depending on what operating system you are and what thread API you are using there is a chance to say if a thread will be user-level or kernel, my source dates back to 2012 and things might have changed since then.

---

#### Bibliography

*Abraham Silberschatz, Peter Baer Galvin, Greg Gagne "Operating System Concepts 9th edition" 2012 Pages 169-171*

Answer (score 1):

In C#, thread pool uses a combined approach (both user-level and kernel-level).

In a combined system, thread creation is done completely in user space, as is the bulk of the scheduling and synchronization of threads within an application. The multiple ULTs from a single application are mapped onto some (smaller or equal) number of KLTs. The programmer may adjust the number of KLTs for a particular application and processor to achieve the best overall results.
In a combined approach, multiple threads within the same application can run in parallel on multiple processors, and a blocking system call need not block the entire process.

---

**Bibliography**

*Operating Systems - Internal and Design Principles (NINTH Edition) William Stalling -  Page 188*